# Java EE persistence. Nested @PostLoad. PostLoad callback method in supercalss

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, superclass

What should happen, if both the entity class and its superclass implements methods annotated with `javax.persistence.PostLoad`? Which method must be called and which as first? Does it dependent on the visibility of the method (private, public)?

(Hibernate default session doesn't calls such methods at all and I am about to implement a workaround using the Hibernate `PostLoadEventListener`.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me copy some parts of the Java Persistence API 2.0 FR specification which I believe might answer your question.

**3.5.1 Lifecycle Callback Methods**

> The callback methods can have **public, private, protected, or package
>   level access**, but must not be static or final.

**3.5.4 Multiple Lifecycle Callback Methods for an Entity Lifecycle Event**

> If multiple classes in an inheritance
>   hierarchy—entity classes and/or mapped superclasses—define entity
>   listeners, **the listeners defined for a superclass are invoked before
>   the listeners defined for its subclasses in this order**.
>
> (...)
>
> If a lifecycle callback method for the same lifecycle event is also
>   specified on the entity class and/or one or more of its entity or
>   mapped superclasses, the callback methods on the entity class and/or
>   superclasses are invoked **after** the other lifecycle callback methods,
>   most general superclass first.

And following section brings a very detailed example which might solve your problem:

**3.5.5 Example**

> There are several entity classes and listeners for animals:
>
> ```
> @Entity
> public class Animal {
>     ....
>     @PostPersist
>     protected void postPersistAnimal() { .... }
> }
>
> @Entity
> @EntityListeners(PetListener.class)
> public class Pet extends Animal {
>     ....
> }
>
> @Entity
> @EntityListeners({CatListener.class, CatListener2.class})
> public class Cat extends Pet {
>     ....
> }
>
> public class PetListener {
>     @PostPersist
>     protected void postPersistPetListenerMethod(Object pet) { .... }
> }
>
> public class CatListener {
>     @PostPersist
>     protected void postPersistCatListenerMethod(Object cat) { .... }
> }
>
> public class CatListener2 {
>     @PostPersist
>     protected void postPersistCatListener2Method(Object cat) { .... }
> }
> ```
>
> If a PostPersist event occurs on an instance of Cat, the following
>   methods are called in order:
>   - postPersistPetListenerMethod
>   - postPersistCatListenerMethod
>   - postPersistCatListener2Method
>   - postPersistAnimal

Hope that helps!